# datatables rejects en dashes

Tags: jquery, unicode, datatables

My server response feeds data from the DB into `datatables` and I get an error when the data fed in the `aaData` segment contains [en dashes](https://unicodelookup.com/#%E2%80%93/1). The error I get is:

> DataTables warning (table id = 'resultTable'): DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error.

I know the en dash causes this because data containing it is the only time I get this error. Is there a way I can encode the data that I feed to datatables, that would prevent this kind of error?

JSON (note the en dash in `test–Data`):

```
{
  "sEcho": 1,
  "iTotalRecords": 1,
  "iTotalDisplayRecords": 1,
  "aaData": [
    [
      "testData|test–Data|test–Data",
      "testData",
      "Published",
      "2016-11-22"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample JSON? Is the character being escaped using `\u2013`?

Comment: it is not being escaped. i was wondering if there is an all inclusive method to escape/encode all the characters that datatables expects

Comment: added the JSON.

Comment: What is the encoding of the JSON data?

Comment: Plain text, as far as I can tell from the server side java module

Comment: What's the server-side code? It sounds like it is encoding the response in something other than UTF-8, probably Windows code page 1252. JSON *must* be transferred in UTF-8.

Comment: Several side Java 7 with Spring